# Jsf-ajax request and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I know that every time that i refresh a part of page with jsf-ajax i lost some plugins like: jquery datatable, masks and others, because JSF can't reload it. So, i need re-init all plugins with a "hack", like this:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(handleAjaxEvents);
```

I really think this is very ugly and not a best practice. I would like to know if there is some way to avoid it, if JSF in next versions can fix it.  Sometimes i need to do a "BIG HACK" to javascript plugins works as i need, because jsf-ajax problem.

Comment: JSF does not try to reload anything... If you need to reapply things to the components, that would be the same problem when doing some sort of ajax without jsf... So there is no jsf-ajax problem, there is a 'ajax-with-used-javascript-components' problem. It is caused by all sorts of javascript-client-side-component suites manipulating the html. Totally not jsf related

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, but there is any better fix to this problem ?

Comment: I have no idea. It is just a mismatch of plain html/jquery components and how jsf updates pages (for which you can exclude parts). E.g. 'real'  jsf components based on jquery do not have this problem (like PrimeFaces datatable). What you can do (or at least try) is to create custom components and do the 'init' in there